# No puedo clonar mi repositorio git porque me dice que no existe

Tags: git, github, repositorio, clone, git-clone

Intento clonar mi repositorio de githab y me dice que no existe.

git clone https://github.com/Fede/repos.git

remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Fede/repos.git' not found

Comment: El repositorio es público? Si no es público, tienes que asegurarte de que tengas bien configurada la autenticación para que github te deje trabajar con él.

Comment: me parece que el que deseas es : https://github.com/fede/fede.git

Answer (score 0):

Es que ese directorio no existe, los repos públicos que tienes son:

```
https://github.com/fede/dummy-api-airline.git
https://github.com/fede/fede.git
https://github.com/fede/empower.dev.git
https://github.com/fede/dog-api.git
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el repositorio: `https://github.com/Fede/repos.git` No existe o es privado!, los repositorios que se muestran son: https://github.com/fede?tab=repositories, entre los cuales me imagino que el que deseas clonar es:

https://github.com/fede/fede.git

como se indica aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Tal y como dice el compañero de arriba, el repositorio no existe, esto lo compruebas pegando el enalce `https://github.com/Fede/repos.git` en el navegador y cuando lo buscas, te lleva a una pagina que no existe.

Ese repositorio no se encuentra creado, crealo, sube el proyecto a ese repositorio y clonalo, sobra decir que si esta creado el repositorio, asegurate de que este publico

Espero haber ayudado